# .NET MAUI Cannot bind to the nested property of model - complaining property is expected

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, maui

Collection view in MAUI is complaining that the model property is not a property and is expecting a property

Below is my problem,

I have a following data model class 'A'

```
public class A
{
  public string Name = string.Empty;
  public List<A> Children = new();
}
```

I have a Controller 'C' whose method 'm' returns A

```
public class C
{
  public A m();
}
```

I have a view model 'V' that calls 'C.m()' and set V's property 'P' as value returned by m

```
public partial class V : ObservableObject
{
  [ObservableProperty] private A _P = new(); //MVVM tool kit creates a public property 'P'

  public V(C c)
  {
    this.GetA(c);
  }

  private void GetA(C c)
  {
     this.P = c.m();
  }
}
```

I am binding my main page to the view model and then trying to show the property P in a nested collection view but it complains that "Name" is a string or Children is a list`1 and **"Property is expected"**

```
<ContentPage
             xmlns:viewModel="[namespace]"
             x:DataType = "viewModel:V">
  <ScrollView>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,auto,*" ColumnDefinitions="auto,*" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="5">

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                BackgroundColor="LightGrey">
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="A"/>
                    <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                    BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="925" 
                                    ItemsSource="{x:Binding P}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:A}">
                                <VerticalStackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{x:Binding  Name,StringFormat='|-- {0}'}"/>
                                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:A}">
                                                <VerticalStackLayout>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='|------ {0}'}"/>
                                                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                                                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:A">
                                                                <Label Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='|---------- {0}'}"/>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                                    </CollectionView>
                                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Border>
    </grid>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Why does it show the error that "Property is expected" and how can I fix it?

Comment: an `ItemsSource` must be `IEnumerable`.  You are using `P` which is not.  If you want to bind to `P`s `Children` property, then use `"{Binding P.Children}"`

Comment: `Children` currently **is not a property**; it is a field. Do `public List<A> Children { get; set; } = new();`

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Good to know that even though it might bind to a property but wont do much unless its a IEnumerable

Comment: Thank you very much! 

good to know a clear distinction between fields and properties. I have used both correctly (most of the time) without a clear distinction of both.